# Bottom magnetic levitation

Tags: gyroscopes, levitation

There are many decorative devices, that keep a small metal sphere levitating in air by attracting it to a top electromagnetic coil while monitoring their height by optical sensors.

There is also the 'levitron' where a passive permanent magnet spinning top is hoovering above some permanent magnets, it's orientation is controlled by gyro forces.

And there are bottom based electromagnetic devices, which keep a disk hoovering in air above them by rotating magnetic fields. Like this one: http://usables24.de/shop/article_GL02.001/Gravity-Lifter-Mini.html

On the first look, it seems simple to exchange the rotation of the top by the rotation of the field.

But: A rotating field must employ the orientation and position control by some electrodynamic means I guess, as the disk is spinning quite slow in these devices, and thus is not stabilized by gyro forces.

What mechanisms are behind this? Maybe the 'levitron' is stabilzed by magnetic forces too, not by the gyro force alone?